# Parse Failed with: TypeError: Cannot call method 'get' of undefined

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I have no idea why I'm getting this error. Please help me out? It's happening at the queryUser.get line.

```
Parse.Cloud.define("getStacksForUser", function(request, response) {

console.log(request);
console.log(response);
var User = Parse.Object.extend("User")
var Stack = Parse.Object.extend("Stack")
var StackUser = Parse.Object.extend("StackUser")

var queryUser = new Parse.Query(User);
queryUser.get(request.object.get("user"), {
    success: function(user) {
        console.log(user);
    },
    error: function(object, error) {
        response.error("Error retrieving User");
    }
});
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't seem that [`request`](https://parse.com/docs/js/symbols/Parse.Cloud.FunctionRequest.html) normally has an `object` property, so `request.object` wouldn't have a `.get("user")` method. Did you maybe mean `request.user`?

Comment: @JonathanLonowski that doesnt seem to work either. It jumps to the error. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found my mistake.
I should do:

`request.params.user` not `request.object.get("user")`

Another thing that I realized was that Parse sends the `PFUser` who is logged in currently along with the request.

Simply doing `request.user` will give you the current user. So I'm going to do that instead of what I was doing in my question.

Comment: This is along the lines of the problem I had with relations: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19692855/parse-cloud-code-cannot-call-method-topointer-of-null-when-calling-query/19692856#19692856