# Parse Cloud Code: "Cannot call method '_toPointer' of null" when calling .query() on a relation

Tags: javascript, parsing, parse-platform

This is something that I struggled with, and couldn't find a quick answer for. Ultimately, I realized that I wasn't reviewing the Parse documentation properly.

**Problem**

If you're reading this question, perhaps you're getting the following error in your Cloud Code error log

```
Result: TypeError: Cannot call method '_toPointer' of null
```

when you try to call the `.query()` method of a `Parse.Relation`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Solution**

Consider that you may be retrieving the relation incorrectly, in the first place. I spent quite a while struggling to understand why, if I called the `.get('RELATION_KEY')` method of a `Parse.Object`, I kept getting this error.

I **should have been calling** `.relation('RELATION_KEY')` instead. I know this <strike>is</strike> was in the Parse.Object documentation, but I saw "get" and stopped reading. My mistake.

Hope it helps.